How to get X Y in isometric tilemap
Im new to Phaser. I  created a isometric map from Tile.
here my code to create my Map:
preload() {
    console.log('pre load mainScene');
   
    Cay1x.preload(this);
    DatTrong.preload(this);
    MoRong.preload(this);
    Player.preload(this);

    // Map assets
    this.load.image('tiles', 'assets/images/map4.png');
    this.load.image('nen_co_2', 'assets/images/nen_co_2.png');

    this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('map', 'assets/images/map4.json');
    this.load.tilemapTiledJSON('mapIsometric', 'assets/images/mapIsometric.json');

    this.load.image('Chest1', 'assets/images/Chest1.png');
}

create() {
    console.log('create');
    
    this.map = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'map' });
    this.mapIsometric = this.make.tilemap({ key: 'mapIsometric' });

    
    console.log('Map:', this.map);
    console.log('MapIsometric:', this.mapIsometric);

    const tileset1 = this.map.addTilesetImage('map4', 'tiles');
    const tilesetIsometric = this.mapIsometric.addTilesetImage('nen_co_2', 'nen_co_2'); 

   
    console.log('Tileset1:', tileset1);
    console.log('TilesetIsometric:', tilesetIsometric);

    
    const layer1 = this.map.createLayer('Tile Layer 1', tileset1, 0, 0);
    const layer2 = this.map.createLayer('Tile Layer 2', tileset1, 0, 0);

   
    const isometricX = 2000; 
    const isometricY = 1000; 

    const layer1Isometric = this.mapIsometric.createLayer('Tile Layer 1', tilesetIsometric, isometricX, isometricY);

And when I try to get X, Y in another Object :
this.input.keyboard.on("keydown-P", (event) => {
            if (this.inventory.selected !== undefined && this.inventory.selected !== null) {
                let selectedItem = this.inventory.selectedItem;

                if (selectedItem && selectedItem.name === 'dat_trong' && this.draggedItem) {
                    let localPoint = new Phaser.Math.Vector2();
                    this.mainScene.cameras.main.getWorldPoint(this.draggedItem.x, this.draggedItem.y, localPoint);

                    // Kiểm tra localPoint
                    console.log(`LocalPoint: x=${localPoint.x}, y=${localPoint.y}`);

                    // Chuyển đổi localPoint sang tọa độ trong mapIsometric
                    let mapIsoX = localPoint.x;
                    let mapIsoY = localPoint.y;

                    // Chuyển đổi mapIsoX và mapIsoY sang tọa độ tile
                    let tileX = this.mainScene.mapIsometric.worldToTileX(mapIsoX);
                    let tileY = this.mainScene.mapIsometric.worldToTileY(mapIsoY);

                    // Kiểm tra tileX và tileY
                    console.log(`TileX: ${tileX}, TileY: ${tileY}`);

                    // Lấy vị trí của tile đó trong thế giới
                    let worldX = this.mainScene.mapIsometric.tileToWorldX(tileX) + 2000;
                    let worldY = this.mainScene.mapIsometric.tileToWorldY(tileY) + 1000;

                    // Kiểm tra worldX và worldY
                    console.log(`worldX: ${worldX}, worldY: ${worldY}`);

                    if (tileX !== null && tileY !== null && worldX !== null && worldY !== null) {
                        new DatTrong({ scene: this.mainScene, x: worldX + this.mainScene.mapIsometric.tileWidth / 2, y: worldY + this.mainScene.mapIsometric.tileHeight / 2, texture: 'atlas_dat_trong' });
                        this.inventory.removeItem(this.inventory.selected);
                        this.refresh();
                        this.draggedItem.destroy();
                        this.draggedItem = null;
                    } else {
                        console.error('Không thể đặt DatTrong, tọa độ tile hoặc tọa độ thế giới không hợp lệ');
                    }
                }
            } else {
                console.log('Selected item is not "dat_trong" or item is not being dragged.');
            }
        });

When I try to get X, Y from the tile map using tileToWorld X', it return null. I can only get Y using tileToWorld Y
Anyone know how to get both X Y from isometric map?

I have some question, regarding your question. With which code are you trying to get X, and Y coordinates? Can you update your question with the relevant function calls of your code that return null? and What are the values for the parameters you pass to the function?

i updated my code.

Thank you for sharing parts of you code, I just have short questions, for somemore context.  What is the value of this.draggedItem is it a tile / image ontop of the tilemap or somewhere else? In the console, what are the values tileX / tileY / worldX / worldY / localPoint.x / localPoint.y ?

This is those value in my console:   LocalPoint: x=2088.0629211511628, y=1448.0345522072394
TileX: null, TileY: null
worldX: undefined, worldY: undefined
Cannot place DatTrong, invalid tile coordinates or world coordinates

Did my question solve your problem, or is it still not working as expected?

Sorry for my late reply. It still not working as expected, because i dont understand how can i use the vector worldToTileXY return

I updated my answer to show how I would use this the vector from the function worldToTileXY  instead of using the functions worldToTileX / worldToTileY. I Hope this works and clears thing up.

The issue could be, that for isometric maps you should use worldToTileXY.
(I'm not 100% sure, since I can't create a running demo for this problem)
Excerpt from the Documentation(link to documentation)

...worldToTileX/ worldToTileY... You cannot call this method for Isometric or Hexagonal tilemaps as they require both worldX and worldY values to determine the correct tile, instead you should use the worldToTileXY method...

Update:
So you could alter your code to this:
...
let vector = this.mainScene.mapIsometric.worldToTileXY(mapIsoX, mapIsoY, false);
let tileX = vector.x;
let tileY = vector.y;

let vector2 = this.mainScene.mapIsometric.tileToWorldXY(tileX);
let worldX = vector2.x + 2000;
let worldY = vector2.y +  1000;
...


Depending on you assets, the third parameter of worldToTileXY and tileToWorldXY might have to be set to true.

